# why does link does not work when it is clicked in the web page

Tags: html, hyperlink

i have  typed the email URL link that has been included into the  tag of the html code 
when the link is clicked it does not open up to an email sending platform

Comment: Hi, can you please add some code

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the link with `mailto:`. So something like:

`<a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a>`